# 'while(doSome())' can i do this?

Tags: php

So...

```
class postQuery {

public function __construct($args = NULL){

    $post_type = $args['post_type'];
    $limit = $args['limit'];
    $category = $args['cat'];

    global $sql;

    $sql = $sql->query('SELECT * FROM posts');
    $sql = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function havePosts() {

    global $sql;
    global $rowNum;

    $rowNum = 0;
    $rowMax = count($sql);

    while($rowNum <= $rowMax) {
        return $rowNum;
        $rowNum++;
    }

}
}
```

the havePosts() function should run while $rowNum < $rowMax... everything ok this far...

but now, i want to create a while statement with this function, like this:

```
$con = new postQuery();

while($con->havePosts()){
    global $sql;
    global $rowNum;

    return $sql[$rowNum]['title'];
}
```

How can i return the data given by my WHILE inside the Function one by one?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Looping over all results?

Comment: one by one? like a cursor?

Comment: @TimWolla, yeah... Loop over all results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `postQuery` class may look like this:

```
class postQuery() {

  private $currentRow = 0;

  public function havePosts() {
    global $sql;
    if ($this->currentRow == count($sql) - 1)
      return FALSE;
    $this->currentRow++;
    return $this->currentRow - 1;
  }
}
```

And then you can loop through posts:

```
while(($rowNum = $conn->havePosts()) !== FALSE) {
  echo $sql[$rowNum]['title'];
}
```

Note that my example is not best practice at all. You should avoid using global variables and lot of data you can store to class member variables (e.g. `count($sql)`). You should also fix my arithmetic to avoid using magic operations like `$this->currentRow + 1`.

Comment: i don't get it... how the $rowNum will be incremented to actually get the array index? (Like $sql[0]['title'], $sql[1]['title'], $sql[2]['title'], etc)

Comment: for some reason, i cannot get the first index (0), i think it's possible because in first statement he returns 0:

'$this->currentRow - 1' in the first time is = 0... and this is returning me nothing, like 0 = FALSE... there someway to RETURN the INTEGER '0'?

Comment: Sorry for that issue, you have to modify while condition to this: `while(($rowNum = $conn->havePosts()) !== FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

Put results in array and the return that array that you can access later

```
public function havePosts() {
  global $sql;
  global $rowNum;

  $rowNum = 0;
  $rowMax = count($sql);
  $titles=array();
 while($con->havePosts()){
    global $sql;
    global $rowNum;

   $titles[]= $sql[$rowNum]['title'];
  }

  return $titles;
```

}